# Reuse Terraform modules for different environments

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-modules

I'm having a hard time to understand how to reuse modules like [terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine) for multiple environments like production, staging and development within one GCP project.

I was used to have a structure like this:

```sh
├── backend.tf
├── development
│   └── development.tfvars
├── firewall.tf
├── gcp-apis.tf
├── gke.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── production
│   └── production.tfvars
├── providers.tf
├── staging
│   └── staging.tfvars
├── variables.tf
├── versions.tf
└── vpc.tf
```

Where I just filled out the .tfvars files with values. Now I got somehow lost with the module structure. Looking at the [terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine example](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/blob/master/cluster.tf#L143-L177) I'm not sure how to define multiple node pools for i.e. with different types of machines/disks.

For me the [example in README.md](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine#usage) doesn't look like a clean separation of template and variables, it seem's to be some kind of mixup (please no offense, I guess I just don't understand it).

To be a little more specific: what do I need to define in my development.tfvars, staging.tfvars and production.tfvars if I want to have multiple node pools?

Hope you can help me out.
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll explain better the `terraform workspace` usage.

If you want to reuse a module or a resource across multiple environments, `terraform workspace` is the better solution. There are some steps that you need to follow.

Let's create the dev and prod workspace:

```
terraform workspace new prod
terraform workspace new dev
```

Let's check if they were created running `terraform workspace list`, you will see something like:

```
  default
* dev
  prod
```

Now we have two workspaces and we are on `dev`. Since we want to reuse the `gke` module, we need to pass everything we want to be changed, using the `workspace` name in a map.

Let's create a file first like `settings.tf`, see the following examples, and feel free to customize everything you want.

```
locals {
  env = terraform.workspace

  disk_size_gb = {
    dev  = 50
    prod = 100
  }

  machine_type = {
    dev  = "e2-standard-2"
    prod = "e2-medium"
  }
...
}
```

Now we need to use our custom configurations in the `gke` module, and all you need to do is:

```
module "gke" {
   source = "terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google"
   project_id = "<PROJECT ID>"
   name = "${local.env}-gke-cluster" #your cluster name will be dev-gke-cluster"
  ...
   disk_size_gb = local.disk_size_gb #50 for dev
   machine_type = local.machine_type #e2-standard-2 for dev
  ...
}
```

When you are done, let's deploy by:

```
terraform workspace select dev
terraform apply
terraform workspace select prod
terraform apply
```

As I said, you can use this approach on modules and resources.. You don't need to duplicate the terraform code, just put the values on the `locals` block as I did and use it where you want.

Comment: Ok, now I've got it! Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it! You can accept/upvote my answer and it can help someone else that have the same issue @mr.szop

Comment: This worked great for me, but I had to change how I accessed the workspace dependent variable, mine looks like size = local.vm_sku["${local.env}"]. Works great!

Answer (score -1):

In Terraform , treat modules like unit blocks where you can call them in different states { environments } or iterate on them using a list .

**environments / workspaces**

create workspace for each environment , and use tfvars files accordingly so each environment tracked into separate state file

```
terraform workspace create/list/switch
```

**Iteration Method**

- use , where you only need identical and variation between envs almost nothing .
- unify your config under a single tfvars file and define lists

use for_each to iterate over a list like

```
module "eks" {
  for_each = var.listed_envs  #where listed envs is a list type variable .
  source = "../path_to_module "
```

check terraform important  functions like yaml encode/decode , can change your variables file to be a yaml based .

Comment: You have an extra dot in `var.listed_envs.`.

Comment: Kindly upvote if found it useful @mr.szop